# how to access camera and microphone in webview ios xamarin form?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, webrtc

we have web application for video call which is done by webrtc. This web video call works fine in android webview, but not working in ios webview. I need to know how i can access camera and microphone in ios webview xamarin form?

Comment: Did you add the permission for camera and microphone in info.plist ?

Comment: yes already added permission

`<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
 <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) camera use.</string>
 <key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
 <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) contacts use.</string>
 <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
 <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) photos and video use.</string>
 <key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
 <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) bluetooth use.</string>
 <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
 <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) microphone use.</string>`